# Create a List in Python from Value of Max Data

Tags: python, list, max, aggregate-functions, data-wrangling

I want to create a list in Python from the dataset below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    `'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',` `'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],` 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_3_MNTH_AGO': [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'F', 'F', 0, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_4_MNTH_AGO' : [0, 2, 'F', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_5_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_6_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_7_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_8_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_9_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_10_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2, 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_11_MNTH_AGO' : [4, 3, 2, 'F', 2, 0, 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO' : ['F', 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2]
})
```

With some data wrangling by transposing the data to convert the value with this code:

```
#Transpose data
dfT = pd.DataFrame(df.T).reset_index(inplace=False)
dfT

#Data converting
df = df.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3}).astype(int).T
df
```

The data frame look like this:
[image]

For example,

```
#in column 0, max value is 8,
#in column 1, max value is 8,
#in column 2, max value is 7,
.....
and so on until column 23.
```

**Final result that I expected should be a list that consists a maximum value from each column:**

```
max_val = [8,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,6,5,...,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_1_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_2_MNTH_AGO': [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_3_MNTH_AGO': [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'F', 'F', 0, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_4_MNTH_AGO' : [0, 2, 'F', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_5_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_6_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 0], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_7_MNTH_AGO' : [3, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_8_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 2, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_9_MNTH_AGO' : [2, 2, 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_10_MNTH_AGO' : [5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2, 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'C'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_11_MNTH_AGO' : [4, 3, 2, 'F', 2, 0, 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
    'CRDACCT_DLQ_CYC_12_MNTH_AGO' : ['F', 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 'C', 'C', 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 'C', 'C', 'F', 2]
})

#Transpose data
dfT = pd.DataFrame(df.T).reset_index(inplace=False)

#Data converting
df = df.replace({'C': -1, 'F': -2, 'Z': -3}).astype(int).T

max_val = list(df.max())

print(max_val)
```

**Output:**

```
[8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```